# AutoComplete is not working in Content Editor Web Part Sharepoint 2013

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013

I have added the code in my content editor webpart. But it is not showing the autocomplete data. 
Reference : https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

[Content Editor screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04xQg.png)

Comment: I would recomend not using jQuery UI and instead learn a library like React or Angular and if you still need a styling framework use material ui or materialize css

Answer (score 0):

After adding 'autocomplete js' and 'jquery' you have to add a input filed with an ID like: The id is `tags`

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

then you have to create a function and your all item in a variable. The variable name is `availableTags`.
Then you have to call your input filed `tags` id with this code in the function.

[source](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

```
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Please check the image I attached. This is what I did. Created a input with id 'tags' and attached the source array. I put input control above script too. that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code into content editor web part or script editor web part.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = ["ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp"];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({ 
        source: availableTags
    });
});
</script>
<input id="tags"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Its working.. I was missing jquery-ui.js reference.. Thanks for the suggestion.. :)
This is the answer but I cant mark as a answer due to my rating.. :)